# How to change the style properties of HTML.Label?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC in asp.net.

i want to change font size & color of html.label control.

so how can i make helper class of this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code for such an extension.  Note that the ParameterDictionary is my own class.  I think the MVC extensions use RouteValueDictionary instead, but it seems wrong to me to rely on that so I made my own class for this specific purpose.  You'll need to import the namespace containing your HtmlExtensions class into the view where you want to use these extensions (and add a reference to the project containing the class if not in your web project).

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string Label( this HtmlHelper helper,
                                string labelFor,
                                string value,
                                object htmlAttributes )
    {
        TagBuilder labelBuilder = new TagBuilder( "label" );
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( labelFor ))
        {
            labelBuilder.Attributes.Add( "for", labelFor );
        }
        labelBuilder.MergeAttributes( new ParameterDictionary( htmlAttributes ) );
        labelBuilder.SetInnerText( value );
        return labelBuilder.ToString( TagRenderMode.Normal );
    }    
}
```

Usage:

```
<%= Html.Label( "Name", new { @class = "input-label" } ) %>
<%= Html.TextBox( "Name" ) %>
```

Comment: Hi i am getting error on  ParameterDictionary => Missing reference

Comment: Yes. ParameterDictionary is my own class.  You could replace it with RouteValueDictionary from the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just do that in the markup (style / css):

```
<label for="Name" ***here***>Name:</label>
```

Comment: Certainly could -- and, in fact, I normally do.  A helper extension can be good, though, to make the construction of labels consistent and testable -- for example, if you always wanted to have a certain class applied you could modify the extension to add it.